# Update record without automatic joins to respective belongsTo associations

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.6

I want to update a record for a specific condition in only items table but when I checked the query, it automatically add joins with it's associated tables. For examples:

```
$this->Item->updateAll(
    array('Item.alg_update' => 0),
    array('Item.id' => 123456),
);
```

it executes following query:

```
UPDATE `DB`.`items` AS `Item` LEFT JOIN   
`DB`.`item_favorites` AS `ItemFavorite` ON  
(`ItemFavorite`.`item_id` = `Item`.`id`) LEFT JOIN  
`DB`.`categories` AS `Category` ON (`Item`.`category_id` =  
`Category`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `DB`.`subcategories` AS `Subcategory` ON  
(`Item`.`subcategory_id` = `Subcategory`.`id`) LEFT JOIN  
`DB`.`item_descriptions` AS `ItemDescriptions` ON  
(`Item`.`description_id` = `ItemDescriptions`.`id`) SET  
`Item`.`alg_update` = 0  WHERE `Item`.`id` = 123456
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [**manual**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions) (last paragraph

> By default, updateAll() will automatically join any belongsTo
>   association for databases that support joins. To prevent this,
>   temporarily unbind the associations.

so you have to do

```
$this->Item->unbindModel(
    array('belongsTo' => array('Subcategory'))
);

$this->Item->updateAll(
    array('Item.alg_update' => 0),
    array('Item.id' => 123456),
);
```

Comment: Hey @arilia, thanks for the answer but is there any way to not write manually every associations? I mean there could be many belongsTo and many update queries in a project.

Comment: not sure if recursive works for `updateAll` too. You can try `$this->Item->recursive = -1` but I don't think it'll work

Comment: I found a method **getAssociated** which could be used to get all associated like `$this->Item->getAssociated()`